# mysql import csv with wrong data

Tags: mysql, import-csv

I am trying to import excel.csv file to mysql and I succeed to import data on mysql
but the data is imported wrongly and I don't know why.
The excel image is real data and the cmd image is the imported data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPy19.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XG8x.png)

PS: Number of Data is 671679

Comment: After performing the query, execute `show warnings;`

Comment: Can you add a sample of the csv file as text to the question please - the fact that the data looks ok in excel does not mean it's good in the csv file. And what's that peculiar symbol in the lines terminated statement?